# How to allow file uploading in PHP without giving full public write permission?

Tags: php, linux, file-upload, upload, permissions

Ok, so I have a file upload script in PHP that used to run fine; but I've just moved it onto a new server.

The new server has the following settings for all website folders (it's running Ubuntu):

[image: http://imgur.com/A7yGYWl]

My old server had the following settings in all website folders, and it allowed file uploads using the same PHP code:

[image: http://imgur.com/aDzZx2n]

Am I missing something? Are these access permissions you have to set for PHP itself? 'file_uploads = On' is set in the php.ini, and everything else related to file uploading set to default.

All I want to do is allow my PHP script to upload images to a specific directory. Am I missing something obvious? Allowing public write permissions allows the script to run correctly, so it's definitely a permission issue and not an issue with the script. But surely allowing public write access is a big security issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should embed the images in the answer instead of just linking to them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the web server software write access to the target directory. If you're running Apache this will conventionally be 'apache'. You can get that information from the `httpd.conf` file. Look at the group to which the directory belongs (use `ls -l`), and add the apache user to that group (`useradd -G myGroup apache`). Then enable group write access.